# How to Single admob ad without refreshing multiple activities in android?

Tags: android, android-activity, admob

Hi I am new to android app development... And developed android app. In the app I have put admob ad in every activity. When I move one activity to another. Everytime ad is reloading. But I want ad don't reload(same ad displays without reload). Please help me best solution for this and give me a example or sample project...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use [FrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html) and [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) with Single `Activity` instead of multiple `Activity` for showing your Views. I have similar kind of requirement. i have done like this.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adView" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:adSize="BANNER"
        app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Design all your views as Fragments and Replace fragments in FrameLayout. When Your Activity is shown then Ad is displayed and when you move from screen to screen it will not reloaded.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Please give me a sample project...

Comment: Here is few links which is helpful to you. (1) https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html  (2) http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html (3) https://guides.codepath.com/android/Creating-and-Using-Fragments

Answer (score 0):

You can create add Programmatically like this

```
AdView adView = new AdView(activity)
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
adView.setAdUnitId(<your-publisher-id>);

// Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
adView.loadAd(adRequest);

// Place the ad view.
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
adContainer.addView(adView, params);
```

So Create `adView` and `adRequest` as a global variable and you can use it any activtiy.See below

Create a Class `AppController`

```
public class AppController extends Application {

    public static AdView adView;
    public static AdRequest adRequest 
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        CreateAddForAllActivityOnce();
    }

  void CreateAddForAllActivityOnce() {

    adView = new AdView(activity)
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId( < your - publisher - id >);

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adRequest.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
   }
 }
```

Open your Manifest and this line to your application tag.

```
<application
        android:name="your.pakacge.name.AppController"
         ....>
```

In your any activity Assume you have layout set gravity bottom.

```
    private LinearLayout add_layout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_finalizing);

         add_layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adView_layout);
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
         add_layout.addView(AppController.adView, params);
    }
```

Same for other activities too.

Comment: Please give me a sample project.... Thanks for advance...

Comment: Get it from here http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-how-to-integrate-google-admob-in-your-app/